# Historic data in membership list

Tags: google-sheets

I run a membership with < 300 members and keep all info in a google sheet (name, contact info, start date, end date, membership type).

I would like to track changes in membership types (we have 3 different) over time for each member so that I can get statistics with historic data.

My solution as of now is the setup below:

- Columns A-G is member info
- Columns K-AU is 2017-data
- Column H is membership type
- Column I/J is Start and end date
- Row A/B/C from column AV is YEAR/MONTH/Membership type

[image]

I then punch in the correct memebership type for each member and each month. This creates a huge  horizontal sheet and is kinda hard to maintain properly. BUT - I get historic data in my statistics.

Any way to do this cleaner and easier in gSheet?

Comment: If it is possible to handle historic data in a way that is cleaner than how I do it as of now. Perhaps more of a question of method than specific formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an approach of typical database normalization here. Keep the list of persons separate, and the list of membership events in its own sheet. This will have the advantage of having to modify things only in 1 place whenever you do things like adding a person or adding a month.

Whenever you need to join the information together, you can then use functionalities like

- pivot table
- =VLOOKUP function
- =QUERY function
- a custom JavaScript to perform a SQL-like JOIN operation

Comment: Thanks for the input! How would you structure the sheet for membership events?